# handle events inside datatable row

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I have a problem with the events inside the [datatable](http://datatables.net).

I have a table and in several columns, I have anchor tags, for example:

```
<tr role="row" class="odd">
  <td class="sorting_1">1</td>
  <td>4.000,00</td>
  <td>
    <a class="js-details" id="9">
      <p class="blue-text">Ver detalle</p>
    </a>
  </td>
  <td>04/09/2017</td>
  <td>
    <a class="icon-checkmark"></a>
    <a class="icon-x red-text js-payment-rejected" href="#" id="9" title="Rechazar el Pago"></a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

And i have these functions:

```
$('.js-payment-approved').click ->
  payment_document_id = $(this).attr('id')
  $.get("#{approved_payment_documents_path}", payment_document_id: payment_document_id)

$('.js-payment-rejected').click ->
  payment_document_id = $(this).attr('id')
  $.get("#{rejected_payment_payment_documents_path}", payment_document_id: payment_document_id)
```

If I click on any of the anchor tags the event won't fire, i read on the datatable forum that I should do something like [this](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/events_live.html):

```
$('.approved-datatable').on 'tr', 'click',  (e) ->
  $('.js-payment-rejected').click ->
    payment_document_id = $(this).attr('id')
    $.get("#{rejected_payment_payment_documents_path}", payment_document_id: payment_document_id)
```

But if I do that I have to click twice the table to fire the event.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `on` method an event handler that you can bind to the event you are interest on, so you don't need to call the `.click` method inside the handler. This should be enough:

```
$('.approved-datatable').on 'click', '.js-payment-rejected', (e) ->
  payment_document_id = $(this).attr('id')
  $.get("#{rejected_payment_payment_documents_path}", payment_document_id: payment_document_id)
```

Pay attention that jQuery `on` needs the event as first parameter, while the second is a selector. For reference [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/on/)